Set multiple styles for pylint naming-styles
Is there a way to set mutltiple types of styles for a *-naming-style, just like you can set multiple bad names which the default .pylintrc uses?
For example:
method-naming-style=camelCase,
                    PascalCase
module-naming-style=snake_case, PascalCase, camelCase


Turns out that the pylint team doesn't want to add this feature.
https://github.com/pylint-dev/pylint/issues/9735
